# How to set multiple passwords to the PDF

Tags: pdf

I am working on an application where I need to set multiple passwords to a single PDF.
Is there any plugin to set multiple passwords to the PDF.

Comment: Generally, with password based security you can have an owner password and a permissions password. The owner password allows the owner to do the things that the permissions password restricts. However, with certificate based security, you can encrypt a document for a specific set of recipients. In that case, you need the public digital certificates from the various recipients which you use to encrypt the file. Then each of the recipients can use their own certificate password to open the document. How you program that functionality depends on the PDF library you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the information @joelgeraci i have tried it but i could not get the proper output. Can you share some examples.

Comment: I'd need a public certificate for you in order to create anything meaningful